# Xamarin.forms navigate to different page in shell from button click on page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, navigation

I am trying to figure out how to navigate through my shell pages from a button click event on the individual pages. I want the button click to be the same as if opening the menu and selecting the next page. For example I will have a series of pages where I gather information from a user to build a report. I want the user to input some data on the first page and click next to go the the 2nd page to enter more information and so on. my reason for wanting to keep the shell page menu is so that if a user decides they need to go back to a page to modify some information previously entered, they can open the shell menu and choose the page as opposed to clicking the back button n times to return to a previous page.

I have tried using routing and Shell.Current.GoToAsync() to achieve this but get a null reference 
in Main.cs at line `UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");`I am avoiding using `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());` because navigating in this manner removes the hamburger menu to my shell page. I have also tried making a function in ShellPage.xaml.cs called Change_Page() which I call via the button click on page one. in this function i have tried the same `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myPage2")` which resulted in the null reference error again as well as trying `Shell.Current.CurrentItem = myPage2;` which resulted in a break at the same line but insstead ogf an error I got some UIKit.UIApllication issue that didn't seem to display an error but did stop the debugger here.

ShellPage.xaml

```
...
<FlyoutItem Title="Page1">
    <ShellContent>
        <views:Page1View Title="Page1" x:Name="myPage1" Route="myPage1"/>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Page2">
    <ShellContent>
        <views:Page2View Title="Page2" x:Name="myPage2" Route="myPage2"/>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Page3">
    <ShellContent>
        <views:Page1View Title="Page1" x:Name="myPage3" Route="myPage3"/>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
...
```

myShellPage.xaml.cs

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MyShellPage : Shell
    {
        public MyShellPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Routing.RegisterRoute("myPage1", typeof(CallInfoPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("myPage2", typeof(SpillInfoPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("myPage3", typeof(ItemsPage));

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
            {
                // Do something
                Current.CurrentItem = myPage3; // throws error 'myPage3' does not exist in current context
                return false; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
            });
        }
    }
```

Page1View.xaml

```
...
<Button Text="Next" Clicked="Next_Clicked" />
...
```

Page1View.xaml.cs

```
...
async void Next_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myPage2");
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to [Register page routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-page-routes) when running .

In the Shell subclass constructor, or any other location that runs before a route is invoked, additional routes can be explicitly registered for any pages that aren't represented in the Shell visual hierarchy:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("pageone", typeof(ItemsPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("pagetwo", typeof(AboutPage));
```

These pages can then be navigated to using URI-based navigation, from anywhere within the application. The routes for such pages are known as global routes.

```
async void NavigateThird_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("pagetwo");
}
```

It works.

[image]

About `AppShell` can not invoke `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myPage2")` or `Shell.Current.CurrentItem = myPage2` in **Constructor** method . In addition , you want to show hamburger menu , you will see `Current.GoToAsync` can not do that . Here you need to use `Current.CurrentItem` to implement that . I have a **workaround** by using `Timer` to invoke them delay for a while .

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Routing.RegisterRoute("pageone", typeof(ItemsPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute("pagetwo", typeof(AboutPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute("pagethird", typeof(PageThird));

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
    {
        // Do something
        Current.CurrentItem = pagethird;
        return false; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });
}
```

**Xaml** code :

```
<FlyoutItem Title="main"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent x:Name="pageone" Title="Page1" FlyoutIcon="icon.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" Route="pageone" />
    <ShellContent x:Name="pagetwo" Title="Page2"
                    FlyoutIcon="icon.png"
                    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" Route="pagetwo" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Two" x:Name="pagethird">
    <ShellContent  Title="Page3"
                    FlyoutIcon="icon.png"
                    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageThird}"
                    Route="pagethird" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I am trying to achieve is keeping the hamburger menu to access my shell on the second page when you clicked the `TOSECONDPAGE` button. so looking at your gif, It would be the same as me opening the shell from the hamburger menu and clicking page2. Instead of having the back button on the second page after clicking the button. Is that possible?

Comment: @tbartlett17 Yeah , you will see that hamburger menu will hied . Using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("pagetwo")` will not avoiding that , you need to use `Current.CurrentItem = pagethird;` can implement what your want . I will update answer .

Comment: can you explain what your timer is doing? also i got an error at your line `Current.CurrentItem = pagethird;` in the timer block. the error was pagethird does not exist in this context.

Comment: @tbartlett17 The Timer is uesd to avoid not working in `Constructor` method directly , that's just a workaround here to make  `Current.CurrentItem` works . You need to check whether declare the `pagethird` in xaml , I will update the xaml code .

Comment: @tbartlett17 `x:Name="pagethird"` should be declared in xaml , then it will work .

Comment: It compiles but crashes after 3 seconds of timer. error at line `UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");` in main.cs traces back to the timer `Current.CurrentItem = myPage3;` "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I updated my code in the original post. my code is mostly the same as what you have, isn't it? edit: what is your AppShell()? i am declaring my routing and timer in MyShellPage.xaml.cs. should i be declaring this elsewhere?

Comment: @tbartlett17 Yeah , you're right . I will share my sample link here , you can check whehter it can work in your local site .

Comment: @tbartlett17 Here is the sample link :https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ua0cxhgfw8sked/AppShellRoute.rar?dl=0  If can not finding the reason, you also can share your sample link here .

Comment: here is a link to my sample project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y7jev7tuo9144i/sample.zip?dl=0

Comment: @tbartlett17 Thanks for sharing , I will check that .

Comment: @tbartlett17 Hi , I have found the reason , you set Tabpage as the Root Page , then this error will occur . If setting `MainPage = new MyShellPage();` , it will work . if you want to make a Shell Application , you should make the ShellPage as the root page first . Based on that , you can custome the sub page inside Shell . Not making other page as the root page .